# Custom namespaced attribute in JSX/React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

As I already figured out, React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags by default. But lets say I have the following component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div><!-- This should contain th:text -->
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I want this component to be rendered to:

```
<div th:text="value">
  ...
</div>
```

How can I achieve, that `th:text="value"` will be added to the rendered output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution a few minutes later:

```
const i18n = {
    "th:text": "${#foo.bar}"
};

render() {
  return (
    <div {...i18n}>
       ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I will as soon as it is available.